# Working with code outside of the Factor source tree

Tags: path, factor-lang

I'm trying to get started playing with factor.

So far, I've:

- downloaded the OSX disk image
- copied the factor directory into `$INSTALL/factor`
- started up the debugger by running `$INSTALL/factor/factor`

Which seems to be running great.

Following [the instructions for writing your first factor program](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/article-first-program-start.html), I noticed that `scaffold-vocab` generated files in my `$INSTALL/factor/work` directory.  Which I can use for now, but in general, I like to keep a separate `$INSTALL` directory-tree and `$CODE` directory-tree.

So I'm trying to follow the instructions from the ["Working with code outside of the Factor directory tree" documentation](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/article-add-vocab-roots.html) to add other directories to the path used to load code into the `factor` executable, but I'm not having much luck.

First, I tried to set a `FACTOR_ROOTS` environment variable:

```
% export FACTOR_ROOTS=.:$CODE/Factor:$INSTALL/factor
% $INSTALL/factor/factor
( scratchpad ) "work" resource-path .
"/usr/local/src/factor/work"
( scratchpad ) ^D
```

Then, I tried to create a `~/.factor-roots` file

```
% echo . > ~/.factor-roots
% echo $CODE/Factor >> ~/.factor-roots 
% echo $INSTALL/factor >> ~/.factor-roots
% $INSTALL/factor/factor        
( scratchpad ) "work" resource-path .
"/usr/local/src/factor/work"
( scratchpad ) ^D
```

Then I checked to see if it should be `./.factor-roots` instead:

```
% mv ~/.factor-roots .
% $INSTALL/factor/factor
( scratchpad ) "work" resource-path .
"/usr/local/src/factor/work"
( scratchpad ) ^D
```

Lastly, I tried adding it manually:

```
% $INSTALL/factor/factor
( scratchpad ) "." add-vocab-root            
( scratchpad ) "$CODE/Factor" add-vocab-root ! no, I didn't actually use an environment variable here :)
( scratchpad ) "work" resource-path .
"/usr/local/src/factor/work"
( scratchpad ) ^D
```

It seems I'm missing something fundamental here.

How do I write code outside of the `$INSTALL/factor` directory-tree and use it in factor? How can I tell `scaffold-vocab` to build scaffolding in my `$CODE/Factor` directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I was able to work out what I was doing wrong thanks to the earnest help of [slava and erg on #concatenative](http://concatenative.org/wiki/view/Concatenative%20IRC%20channel).

Simply put, [`resource-path`](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-resource-path%2Cio.pathnames.html) is not a way to test your factor roots.  Like the docs say it "resolve[s] a path relative to the Factor source code location."

A more effective test is simply [`vocab-roots get`](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-vocab-roots,vocabs.loader.html), which will fetch the current list of vocab roots.

`"/path/to/wherever" add-vocab-root` will add `/path/to/wherever` to your list of vocab-roots, and allow you to do `"/path/to/wherever" "project" scaffold-vocab` so you can build scaffolding in the desired location.

As erg said:

> i usually make another word, like
>  
>   `: scaffold-games ( vocab -- ) [ "/home/erg/games" ] dip scaffold-vocab ;`
>   `"minesweeper" scaffold-games`

Comment: If you need to run at startup a program from a freshly added vocab root, you may simply force compilation with << >> in .factor-rc (that's what I did in mine): << "games" home swap append-path add-vocab-root >> because AFAIK .factor-rc is entirely parsed before compiled.